# How to convert a Java web application to Grails?

Tags: grails

I have a small Java web application built and I'd like to convert this to a Grails web application. My Java web application consists of Servlets, entity and hibernate for the database, and plain old java objects classes. So What's the best way of going about doing this?

Comment: It's not "Groovy on Grails", it's just "Grails". Please read http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1213 and share with your colleagues

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Joshua for the most part.  I have helped prototyped moving a java web service to Grails.  I would first start with understanding the roles of the classes inside Grails (Domain classes, Controllers, Services, Filters, and CommandObject) and mapping on a whiteboard what does those roles in your current application.  With hibernate as the database layer, that *should* be easy to port, and many service like classes can be moved over as-is.  The tear up is going to come at the controller level, so make sure you think that through carefully.

You might think about refactoring your code in the Java space first if your current application does not separate responsibilities well.  The cleaner your code, the more you can re-use as Grails services.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with an empty Grails project I would begin by using your existing POJOs and creating Domain classes in the Grails project. From there I would then begin to model the behavior of the Servlets into Grails controllers, services, and filters. Finally I would finish with cleaning up the views and applying the styles.

That's how I would approach converting it.

Comment: So how would a Servlet class be converted to a grails controller or services, how are requests handled in groovy on grails?

Comment: I would recommend you start by reading the entire documentation for Grails. Honestly it will be worth the effort and will answer all the questions on how to convert your application. http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/