# I try to convert my project using GGTS on grails and have this error {No matching Grails Install (required <unknown>) for project 'XXX'}

Tags: java, servlets, grails, groovy

I using a GGTS(Groovy/Grails Tool Suite and I'm try to convert a java servlet project on Grails using (right click over the project and tab configure and click convert to Grails project) and receive this error?

Configuring Grails Dependency Management has encounter a problem.

No matching Grails Install (required ) for project 'Name of my Project'

Well I have install grails 2.4.4!
I see on windos.preference tab Goovy tab grails I have Grails 2.4.4 Instaled?

Thank you
Edgardo

Comment: sounds like some form of an issue when it tries to do whatever it is that tries to convert it. In all honesty this sounds rather new as in never heard of it before. I would suggest if there is such a thing / process you find out what the command line of it is on grails so you do it from command line rather than within ggts. Personally I think maybe it's time to start a new grails project and change the servlet code to grails since it is going to be very different in structure I would have thought

Comment: Hi Vahid, Well I try to use the wizard tool on ggts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22384620/how-to-convert-a-java-web-application-to-grails  - ggts is buggy to say the least. Never tried that option. It is not an available feature within grails itself. GGTS is no longer supported so you can't even report it as a bug - good luck with that one